# Graph between string value and its corresponding integer value using Dygraph

Tags: javascript, php, dygraphs

How to plot graph between from following data

```
SushmaSwaraj    2612735
ChouhanShivraj  824914
HeadlinesToday  521271
ProBotiZ    19
rogerfederer    2867506
swedishousemfia 2144845
ZeeNews 1070612
```

using Dygraph

Another method is also helpful

Comment: dygraphs is for plotting time series. This doesn't look like a time series. If you want a bar chart for a categorical variable, you should consider another library.

Comment: Examples of any library